# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with reinforcement learning control of cassie robot

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I was trying to simulate the reinforcement learning for cassie robot mujoco, https://github.com/CassieRL/cassierl.

I set up a folder called cassierl in home, and build up 3 folders, one folder is called cassierl which include the source code, one folder is called rllab downloaded from git hub, and one folder is called Thirdparty it is relevent source code from cassierl source code.

my environment variable setup in `/.bashrc`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/.mujoco/mjpro150/bin
export workspacePath=~/cassierl
export PYTHONPATH=$workspacePath/rllab:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
```

After applying make on the src folder, when I run the comman **python3 squatting.py**

```
import cassie2d
import numpy as np

env = cassie2d.Cassie2dEnv()
env.reset()

freq = 0.5
w = freq*3.1415
t = 0.0

while (True):
    env.standing_controller_jacobian(0.7 + 0.25*np.sin(w*t), 
0.25*np.cos(w*t))
    t = t + 0.0005
```

(note, the cassie2d is inside the github source)

the `control mode = PD` was displayed, however, there is error:
Segmentation fault (core dumped).

I would like to know if my folder setting and environment setting are correct or not, to make sure if those steps are the reason why causing the issue.

I will appreciate if anyone could solve this problem, thank you :)

Comment: Is your coder working on a smaller dataset? I sometimes observed a (non-reproducable) segmentation fault in case there is not enough memory left ...

Comment: HI quant, I am totally new to python, could you please explain it more specifically on this question? Thank you very much :)